# Flash Builder 4.6 fails to launch silently

Tags: flash-builder, launch

I have been using Flash Builder 4.6 for a sometime now to develop some android apps. This morning I try to start it and Flash Builder would open the splash screen and silently close. I have renamed the old work space but it created a new work space and closed again silently. I tried to rename the metadata folder, Flash Builder recreated a new metadata folder and closes again. I tried to follow these http://agileui.blogspot.com/2009/09/flashbuilder-4-silently-fails-while.html instructions but I get an error that

> Gumbo.exe is not recognized as an Internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

So guys please help me, it is very frustrating to fight something which gives no errors. I am using windows 7.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a workspace.metadata.log file showing errors?  Execute `eclipse -clean` from a command line.

Comment: @Thanks Jason, but i posted the answer below that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling I found this on http://support.muse.adobe.com/thread/1022320

- Make sure you are connected to the internet.
- Launch a regular  CS6 product other than Acrobat or Flash Builder (for example: Photoshop, After Effects, Premier Pro, InDesign, Flash
  Professional, Illustrator, Dreamweaver.)
- Click on Help->Deactivate .  Deactivate the application. Quit
  application.
- Launch a regular  CS6 product other than Acrobat or Flash Builder (for example:   Photoshop, After Effects, Premier Pro, InDesign,
  Flash Professional, Illustrator, Dreamweaver.)
- Accept Eula.
- Register trial by signing in. Let the app launch.
- Quit and relaunch the app. Wait for UI to come.
- Click on License This Software button on the UI.
- Click on Sign in .
- Serial number screen will come.Enter the serial number in the serial number screen and click Next..
- Close the app if its still running.Relaunch the app while connected on the internet .

Hope this helps